# install tomcat on Windows : JRE_HOME not defined correctly

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have set `JRE_HOME` environment variable to `C:\Programmes\Java\jre.1.8.0_66`
When I run `startup.bat`, I get this error message :

> The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you defined JRE_HOME variable?

Comment: in system variables. when i type echo %JRE_HOME% i am getting the path

Comment: `cd %JRE_HOME%` works from a newly opened command prompt?

Comment: I installed tomcat7 as a service (executable file from apache website). and the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: What is the contents below your JRE_HOME folder? It seems the folder can be located but it does not have the correct structure or is missing files.